# Unable to update existing(Or) related leads while lead convertion

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, exception, salesforce-id

Currently, I'm working on the parent-child relationship on the lead object. So, we are restricting users to convert only master lead & then top 20 related leads will be converting as contacts to the same account.

And we want to update existing unwanted related leads to mark the status as not required & update other fields too.

```
public class RelatedContacts
{
    public Static List<Contact> Relatedcontacts = new List<Contact>();
    public static integer count=0;
    public Static List<Lead> OtherLeads = new List<Lead>();
    public static void LeadConvertion(Map<Id,Id> RelatedLeads) 
    {
        List<Database.LeadConvert> converts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        String convertedStatus = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = TRUE LIMIT 1].MasterLabel;
            for(Lead Ls:[Select id,Parent_Lead__c from lead where Parent_Lead__c=:RelatedLeads.keyset()])
            {
                If(Ls.Parent_Lead__c <> null && count <20)
                {
                    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
                    lc.setLeadId(Ls.Id);
                    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertedStatus);
                    lc.setAccountId(RelatedLeads.get(Ls.Parent_Lead__c));
                    lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
                    converts.add(lc);
                    count =count+1;
                }
                if(Ls.Parent_Lead__c <> null && count >=20)
                {
                    //Lead lss=new lead();
                    Lead ll=new Lead(Id = Ls.Id);
                    //ll.id=Ls.id;
                    Count=Count+1;
                    //ll.Status='Not Visible';
                    ll.Parent_Lead__c='';
                    OtherLeads.add(ll);
                    //OtherLeads.add(lss);
                }    
            }
        If(!OtherLeads.isEmpty())
        {
            Update OtherLeads;
        }
        Database.convertLead(converts, false);
    }
}
```

My Problem is: when I try to convert a lead I'm getting this error.

> 5:28:05.55 (2030963109)|DML_END|[1738] 05:28:05.55
>   (2031063455)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[1738]|System.DmlException: Update
>   failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Q0p000001FrJvEAK; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, UpdateTerritories:
>   execution of AfterUpdate
>
> caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id:
>
> Class.RelatedContacts.LeadConvertion: line 42, column 1
>   Trigger.UpdateTerritories: line 110, column 1: [] 05:28:05.55
>   (2031459688)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1738]|Bytes:322

Comment: Can you add the error you are receiving?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Are you receiving error on this line -- `ll.Parent_Lead__c='';` What is the type of `Parent_Lead__c` field?

Comment: It is lookup field to the lead object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
ll.Parent_Lead__c='';
```

Based on your comments, `Parent_Lead__c` is a lookup field which can contain only `Id` values and that you are trying to assign an *empty string* to it, which is resulting in the error.

If you are creating a new record out there, you don't need to assign anything to this field, you can simply leave it as is without the need of setting a value out there. If you are re-parenting then you can assign a `null` value to the field.

Comment: I have updated the code. But it's taking too much time to convert even I don't know whether it's working or not

Comment: @Pavantej That will classify as a [different question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) based on the format of SFSE. You may like to open a new one with all the applicable details.The answer to the current question was to address the *specific issue* that you were having.